# Am trying to implement push down notification but ".build()" is showing error and i don't know why

Tags: java, android

here is my java file

```
public class two extends Fragment {
EditText ed1, ed2, ed3;

public two() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    ed1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText3);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

}
public void sendNotification(View v){
    String Name = ed1.getText().toString().trim();
    String Tittle = ed2.getText().toString().trim();
    String Question = ed3.getText().toString().trim();

    NotificationManager notif = (NotificationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification n = new Notification.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).
            setContentText(Question).
            setContentTitle(Tittle + "-" + Name).
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.map).build();
            notif.notify(0,n);
}
}
```

the build() on the second to the last line showing error don't know why please what do I have to do thank you

Comment: "showing error" — **what** error?

Comment: where you use `build()` and where you called `sendNotification()` method?

Comment: just the build()

Answer (score 1):

You can Try This..

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
                .setContentText("Notification Content")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setChannelId(channelId)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(YOUR_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Here I Used `NotificationCompat` instead of `Notification`

You can Give any integer value to `YOUR_NOTIFICATION_ID` and string value to`channelId`

Comment: I tried it but the ChannelId is giving me error.. am new to java so i may not understand how to go about it

Comment: You can simply add channelID like this,  String channelID = "channel_id_notification";   and you can simply use this string in your notification.